# SQL Server Import JSON subgroup array

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a code excerpt of a SQL Server script that reads the JSON files and inserts into a table.
I am stuck with a section of the file that is an array. Example:

```
                        "top": 19.2743,
                        "bottom": 20.3115,
                        "left": 0.2878,
                        "right": 1.7038,
                        "isInternalToDevice": false,
                        "numberOfLegs": 3,
                        "legs": [
                            3,
                            2
                        ],
```

I am trying to get the "legs, as "3,2"

Here is the code that reads everything else - just need the legs (to stand on :-) )

```
DECLARE @JSONRoot VARCHAR(50)
SET @JSONRoot = '$._embedded.symbols'
 SELECT     
    [id],
    [description],
    [displayCategoryProgrammaticName],
    [displayCategoryProgrammaticNameDisplay],
    [manufacturer],
    [model],
    [modelqualifier],
    [ProgrammaticName],
    [Type],
    [Position],
    [Label],
    [ReceptacleType],
    [ConnectorType],
    [NumberOfLegs]
  FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'D:\Test\TestFileSymbols.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn, ''+@JSONRoot+'')
WITH
(
    [id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    [description] VARCHAR(200),
    [displayCategoryProgrammaticName] VARCHAR(50),
    [displayCategoryProgrammaticNameDisplay] VARCHAR(50),
    [manufacturer] VARCHAR(100),
    [model] VARCHAR(100),
    [modelqualifier] VARCHAR(100),
    [openings] NVARCHAR(MAX)'$.openings' AS JSON
)
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(openings)
WITH (
    [ProgrammaticName] VARCHAR(100) N'$.programmaticName',
    [Type] VARCHAR(100) N'$.type',
    [Position] VARCHAR(100) N'$.side',
    [Label] VARCHAR(30) N'$.label',
    [ReceptacleType] VARCHAR(100) N'$.receptacleType',
    [ConnectorType] VARCHAR(50) N'$.connectorType',
    [NumberOfLegs] INT N'$.numberOfLegs',
    JSON_QUERY([openings], N'$.legs') AS Legs 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to return `$.legs` using the [`AS JSON` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) and then you can query that further, if needed, to transform it into a comma-delimited string by way of [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql), e.g.:

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(max) =
N'{
    "top": 19.2743,
    "bottom": 20.3115,
    "left": 0.2878,
    "right": 1.7038,
    "isInternalToDevice": false,
    "numberOfLegs": 3,
    "legs": [
        3,
        2
    ]
}';

select *
from openjson(@json) with (
    [NumberOfLegs] int N'$.numberOfLegs',
    [Legs] nvarchar(max) N'$.legs' as JSON
) shredded
outer apply (
    select string_agg(value, ',') from openjson(Legs)
) joined(Leggy);
```

Which returns the results:

| NumberOfLegs | Legs | Leggy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | [ 3, 2 ] | 3,2 |

Comment: Hi AlwaysLearning - thank for this - though still not working I see the data from my SQL script in the BulkData when I replace the column names with "*" though when I apply your suggestions (played with multiple placement in my SQL I do not get any errors only no data. I will post the complete JSON file for you reference to assist in getting closer!  MUCH APPRECIATED

Comment: Not sure how to include a 40Kb file to the post...